# CasperJS : clickLabel not working

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a simple link I want to follow

`<a href="#page-2" class="">next</a>` (Page-2 increments)

I am trying to follow the next button using clickLabel, but I cant seem to get it to work.  It seems to go to the next page then die

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    waitTimeout: 10000,
    stepTimeout: 10000,
    verbose: true,
    pageSettings: {
        webSecurityEnabled: false
    },
    onWaitTimeout: function () {
        this.echo('** Wait-TimeOut **');
    },
    onStepTimeout: function () {
        this.echo('** Step-TimeOut **');
    }
});
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start();
casper.open("removed");

function getAllPages() {


        if (casper.exists(x('//a[text()="next"]'))) {
            casper.echo("Fire")
            casper.clickLabel('next')
            casper.then(getAllPages);

        } else {
            casper.echo("END")
        }
}

casper.then(getAllPages);
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the page was not loading fast enough, this works

```
function getAllPages() {

    if (casper.exists(x('//a[text()="next"]'))) {
        casper.echo("Fire")
        var selected = casper.getElementInfo(x(".//*[@class='selected']")).html;
        casper.echo(selected)
        casper.clickLabel('next', 'a')
        this.wait(2000, function () {
            casper.then(getAllPages);
        });


    } else {
        casper.echo("END")
    }
}
```

Comment: Also notice the 'a' on the end of clickLabel